# JPA How to get data from database after local modification but before commit

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider the below scenario:

```
User user1 = userRepository.findOne(userId); //1
user.setName("xyz");
User user2 = userRepository.findOne(userId); //2
```

On state #1 user1 contains data which exist in database. But on state #2 user2 object contains updated user object (name changed).

How can I get original data from database on state #2

Comment: What about refresh? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I tried this but refresh will clear persistent context and later when saved updated object it giving error.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? You can just copy object which you obtained on first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is against the grain of JPA. One of the core ideas behind JPA is that each entity is represented by exactly one instance in an `EntityManager` if you modify that, there is no "old" instance anymore because there is just one. If you reload it, it will be the same modified instance.

There are various ways to circumvent this.

1. Evict the instance from the `EntityManager` then reload. As you already noticed in the comments the modified instance is now no longer managed and won't automatically saved, which probably isn't what you want.
2. Select the information into a Pojo, not an entity. Often you will only need few specific attributes. If you load them via a native query (`@Query( ..., nativeQuery = true`), this will go straight to the database and when your modified entity didn't get flushed in the meantime, it will see the old data, or depending on transaction isolation levels a version modified by another transaction.
3. You can just copy the entity by copying each property into a fresh instance.